# Batch - Insert texts in between lines of a text file

Tags: batch-file, text, data-manipulation

I've been skimming thru other SO threads but I can't seem to find an idea on how to implement mine via batch script.

I'm figuring out how can I add the strings "Minimum:", "Average:" and "Maximum:" in between the values that has its own line.

Sample Input text file:

```
Server1
1ms
90ms
100ms

Server2
4ms
16ms
20ms

Server3
8ms
78ms
154ms
```

Sample Output file should be:

```
Server1
Minimum: 1ms
Average: 90ms
Maximum: 100ms

Server2
Minimum: 4ms
Average: 16ms
Maximum: 20ms

Server3
Minimum: 8ms
Average: 78ms
Maximum: 154ms
```

Please note that the Server Names may not be sorted in any order as well as the values, they are output from the server. But the input file will be in that format.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your question sounds like an off topic code writing request. What have you tried to far - where did you got stuck. Don't expect others to put more effort in **your** task than you yourself.

Comment: Is ther order of the ms lines really undetermined? If yes simply sort them ascending. Use a 'for /f' to iterate the lines of the file, store server name and append the values to it. BTW a .csv output file seems much more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't shown any effort to write your own solution, so don't request any explanation of this *free* code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set i=27
set s=Minimum: Average: Maximum: ^


(for /F %%a in (input.txt) do (
   for %%i in (!i!) do echo !s:~%%i,9!%%a
   set /A "i=(i+9)%%36"
)) > output.txt
```